# Derivative of ReLu at 0 in practice

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, derivative

I used ReLu for hidden layer for the simple neural net XOR problem. My first attempts failed, because as derivative I used:

```
def drelu(x):
    return 0 if x < 0 else 1
```

But when I used:

```
def drelu(x):
    return 0 if x <= 0 else 1
```

It succeeds and it's faster than sigmoid for the hidden layer.

I read in many places there is no derivative of ReLu at 0 point, mathematically speaking, and people use either 0 or 1. But I think I never saw anywhere saying it must be explicitly 0. Is there a difference in more real world problem? Could it be because XOR problem is simple, the <= made a difference? And what normally people use for 'derivative' of relu?

Comment: shouldn't matter - are you initializing weights properly?

Comment: weights initialization is random uniform from -0.5 to 0.5. generally it works for relu'(x) with <=0 while <0 doesn't work. i also tried to increase hidden units to no avail.